# How to print statement outside loop to avoid duplicates?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I would like my print statement to be outside the loop so the statement doesn't print the same thing over and over. The for loop below simply checks a number from one array against another to find out how many matches have been found. Defining the variables above and printing the statements below results in a "variable not initialised error" which is understandable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    int chkNum = myArray[i];
    int lottMtch = count(chkNum, rndNum);

    if (lottMtch > 0)
    {
        System.out.println(lottMtch + "matches found");
        System.out.print(chkNum);
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("no matches found");
    }
}
```

Comment: error at what line and which variable? can you print that error statement in full?

Comment: If you don't want to print every iteration, move the print statement out of the loop.  If you need a value from inside the loop to do the print, you must assign that value to a variable that's declared outside the loop.

Comment: The error is "The local variable chkNum and lottMtch may have been initialised". This happens because they are declared outside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this would not really make sense ..
if you want than Try this ...

```
        int lottMtch[]=new int[myArray.length];
           Arrays.fill(lottMtch, 0);
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                int chkNum = myArray[i];
               lottMtch[i] = count(chkNum, rndNum);

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                       if (lottMtch[i] > 0)  
                            System.out.println(lottMtch[i] + " matches found "+ myArray[i]);
            }
```

If you wan to found just how many match of `rndNum` in `myArray` Than try this

Here i assume `rndNm` is `global`

```
        int lottMtch=0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {

               lottMtch += count(myArray[i], rndNum);

            }

                       if (lottMtch> 0)  
                            System.out.println(lottMtch + " matches found "+ rndNum);
```

As per discussed in comment Try this ..

```
Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();


       for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
         {
             Integer chkNum = myArray[i];
            Integer cnt = (Integer)count(myArray[i], rndNum);
              if(cnt>0)
              {
                  if(map.get(chkNum)==null)
                     map.put(chkNum,1);
                  else
                     map.put(chkNum, map.get(chkNum)+1);
              }

         }

         for (Object key : map.keySet()) 
             System.out.println(map.get(key) + " matches found "+key.toString());
```

Comment: Don't really understand it but works. Prints both number of matches and the numbers that matched. Only thing is I rather have one statement with number of matches found and the actual numbers in one line.

Comment: So can you give example ?

Comment: are you try to found how many match found with `rndNum` in `myArray` ?  so if `rndNum=23` and `myarry={11,23,33,23}` so u need your output like `2 matches found of 23`.
If you need somthing like this i have edited my answer again

Comment: Yes, but rndNum has six numbers. This is what I got with your previous answer: `code 1 matches found 23 1 matches found 23`. I would like: `code 2 matched found 23`.

Comment: So `rndNum` is array ?? . and your method like this `public int count(int nub ,int []rndNum)`

Comment: yes it's an array, and yes that's the method except it starts with static.

Answer (score 3):

Declare the variable before the loop and then do your stuff in the loops, like adding one to the variable if it is found, then print it out afterwards if it is more than 0. Something like this...

```
int var = 0;
for(...) {
   if(found)
       var++;
}
if(var > 0)
    sysout(var);
```

Of course this code won't work but it is a start. For your learning experience I will let you implement this idea with your code.

Comment: Does print number of matches, but two problems. Firstly, no matches is printed every time there is not match, I only want this if there are no matches at all. Secondly, no solution for chkNum.

Answer (score 2):

This is because if you only declare the variables above the loop and only initialize said variables in the loop, when you attempt to print them outside of the loop, there's no guarantee that they would have been initialized.

So, perhaps you want something like this:

```
int lottMtch = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    int chkNum = myArray[i];
    lottMtch += count(chkNum, rndNum);
    //System.out.print(chkNum); this would not really make sense outside of the loop
}

if (lottMtch > 0)
{
    System.out.println(lottMtch + "matches found");
}
else 
{
    System.out.print("no matches found");
}
```

Comment: comparing lottMuch variable outside of for loop doesnt seem to making any sense, since its value will be depend on the last iteration of loop

Comment: @OnurA. Fixed it by initializing it to `0` and then adding `count()` to it in the loop.

Comment: Good answer. +1 for a +1? ;)

Comment: @ethio this was intentional. It doesn't make sense to print it outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a variable outside the loop if you plan to access it after the loop exits.

Answer (score -2):

You need to initialise variables outside the loop. Try this:

```
int chkNum = 0;
int lottMtch = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    chkNum = myArray[i];
    lottMtch = count(chkNum, rndNum);

}

if (lottMtch > 0)
{
    System.out.println(lottMtch + "matches found");
    System.out.print(chkNum);
}
else {
    System.out.print("no matches found");
}
```

Comment: Not only that, it's bad advice.  He says "initialize" but doesn't.